# Using Lambda with Dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to use LINQ to retrieve some data from a dictionary.

```
    var testDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    testDict.Add(1, "Apple");
    testDict.Add(2, "Cherry");

    var q1 = from obj in testDict.Values.Where(p => p == "Apple");
    var q2 = from obj in testDict.Where(p => p.Value == "Apple");
```

The above lines, q1 and q2, both result in a compiler error.

```
error CS0742: A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause
```

How do I go about using LINQ to find values in a dictionary?

Thank you,

Rick

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Either

```
var q1 = from obj in testDict.Values where obj == "Apple" select obj;
```

or

```
var q1 = testDict.Where(p => p.Value == "Apple");
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason this works is that the dictionary acts as an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKeyType, TValueType>>

Comment: Second expression should also have p.Value == "Apple" as p will be a Pair<,>.

Comment: Those will get you an expression that returns an IEnumerable result.  If you actually want the actual object, you have to call Single() or First()

Answer (score 8):

you have an extra "from obj in" in your statements that isn't needed.  Either remove that or change the .Where to the linq query syntax instead of the method syntax.

```
var q1 = from obj in testDict.Values
         where obj.Value == "Apple"
         select obj;    
var q2 = testDict
         .Where(p => p.Value == "Apple");
```

Comment: First expression should also have p.Value == "Apple" as p will be a Pair<,>.

Comment: Not true, he's selecting from testDict.Values, which is an IEnumerable<string>. He'd only get KeyValuePairs if he selected from testDict itself.